# What is AppStateTracker in an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

An extension called AppStateTracker is causing issues on my Azure web app, what extension is this?
what is it, and why are we only seeing it on one services. What differs that service from the rest of our services. I see it in the Activity Log when I check the JSON for the "Update website extensions"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppStateTracker is an update which enables config level tracking for your web app from Application Change Analysis blade and simply collects data from the environment. So frequent changes to your application will create frequent updates but will have no adverse effects on your application.

AppStateTracker is a dormant extension, it gets activated when Azure makes PUT calls to the application. It would wake up your process if its not always on, however in terms of actual impact on the application - there is nothing invasive that can affect anything. It only scans environment variables and settings and never attaches or does anything with running process nor modify anything. It is part of Change Analysis which is a completely independent product.

If you want to see less of these updates, you can choose to disable file and configuration change tracking on web app following the instructions below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/change-analysis#application-change-analysis-in-the-diagnose-and-solve-problems-tool.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed answer!